# VPython installation error on Windows

Tags: python-2.7, vpython

```
>>> import visual
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import visual
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visual\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from visual.visual_all import * # this statement not included in vis/__init__.py
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visual\visual_all.py", line 10, in <module>
    from visual_common.cvisual import vector
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I got this error when i tried to import visual on 2.7.9 Whats wrong?

Comment: What is wrong is obvious: you don't have the right version of numpy to use with your "visual" package. The latter expects v9, you have v7, so it fails. Now why this happens is another story. VPython's installer may be broken, or maybe you installed from source (and expected your own, older numpy to work), etc. Please tell us more about your system, what you did, etc. Note that even with this information I'm not sure SO is the right place to get an answer. The VPython mailing list/forum/whatever might be a better fit.

Comment: @Tibo : Well i uninstalled my older version of numpy and installed 1.9.1 version then i installed vpython 6.10 from vpython.org, then i tried to import the visual in VIDLE then i got following error:

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\visual_common\materials.py", line 70
    self.__setattr__(key, value)
FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise object comparison in the future.